# Calculating runtimes in a Windows batch file over a month

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm currently using `%time%` to calculate runtimes of several processes.  This is running successfully when running over 24 hours, even over several days. I am however getting negative results when a run is executed at the last day of one month, then completed at the beginning of the following month.  I was hoping someone out there has also run into this issue and has a fix, before I try to resolve this myself.

```
@echo %%time%% = %time%
@FOR /f "tokens=1-2" %%i in ('time /t') do @(
SET EHrMin=%%i
SET Eampm=%%j
)
::
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Second /Format:table ^| findstr /r "."') DO ( 
set Day=%%A
set Hour=%%B
set Minute=%%C
set Second=%%D 
) 
set Milisecond=%time:~9,2%  
set /a
End=%Day%*8640000+%Hour%*360000+%Minute%*6000+%Second%*100+%Milisecond%
set /a Diff=%End%-%Start%
set /a DiffMS=%Diff%%%100 
set /a Diff=(%Diff%-%DiffMS%)/100 
set /a DiffSec=%Diff%%%60 
set /a Diff=(%Diff%-%Diff%%%60)/60 
set /a DiffMin=%Diff%%%60 
set /a Diff=(%Diff%-%Diff%%%60)/60 
set /a DiffHrs=%Diff%

:: format with leading zeroes 
if %DiffMS% LSS 10 set DiffMS=0%DiffMS!% 
if %DiffSec% LSS 10 set DiffMS=0%DiffSec%
if %DiffMin% LSS 10 set DiffMS=0%DiffMin%
if %DiffHrs% LSS 10 set DiffMS=0%DiffHrs%
cls
echo+
echo    Approximate Model Runtime: %DiffHrs% hours %DiffMin% minutes
```

[screenshot of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiU9i.jpg)

Comment: What version of DOS are you targeting?

Comment: Probably gonna have to show your work.